# How to redirect to return URL after AzureADB2C login

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, blazor

I have a Blazor server app with AzureADB2C auth. I use path for different projects, like ~/project1 or ~/project2. User has access to different projects, which is managed by another service.

When unauthorized user navigate to ~/project1 he is redirected to login page like this

**MainLayout.razor**

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
...
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <RedirectToLogin />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

RedirectToLogin using a bit modified code from AzureADB2C.UI package

```
            var uri = new Uri(_navigationManager.Uri);
            var redirectUri = "~" + uri.AbsolutePath;
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo($"AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn?redirectUri={redirectUri}", true);
```

Modification look like that

```
        [HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
        public IActionResult SignIn([FromRoute] string scheme, [FromQuery] string redirectUrl)
        {
            scheme ??= AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Content(redirectUrl) },
                scheme);
        }
```

Redirect URI in AzureADB2C is http://localhost:44377/signin-oidc
And I end on ~/ page.

I completely lost here, the only solution I see here is a cookie used to store and restore redirectUrl

Comment: Is the Redirect URI in the code and in the portal the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can persist URI the user should be returned to by adding "state" parameter to your Azure AD request, see description on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect

A way it could be implemented:

1. Create some object with ReturnUri property and set the value you need the user to be returned to.
2. Serialize object to JSON and encode to BASE64 to get plain string.
3. Add this string as a "state" parameter value:

```
    _navigationManager.NavigateTo($"AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn?redirectUri={redirectUri}&state={your_object_as_encoded_string}", true);
```

5. Once a user will get back to your redirect URI you just grab the state parameter from the current URI value (Azure will return State param back to you).
6. Decode and deserialize state object and redirect the client to the proper URL.

Comment: Have you got a code sample? I have added "state" parameter as you mentioned, but I am not able to retrieve it because the Navigation.Uri in the Authentication.razor OnLogInSucceeded Blazor WebAssembly give me no query parameter. 
I neither can see state parameter in browser network tab with "preserve log".